# Java - gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.Verify Pathfinder Package Doesn't Exist

Tags: java, path-finding

I am attempting use Java Pathfinder and I have pathfinder working.

```
import gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.Verify;
```

> ```
> user.java:2: package gov.nasa.jpf.jvm does not exist
> import gov.nasa.jpf.jvm.Verify;
> ```

I need to use the Verify.random function. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem? I don't really understand how the importation of what I am assuming is a URL works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a URL at all (except in the case of applets, and you didn't mention an applet). You need to put the Pathfinder jar in the classpath when compiling and running, via -cp to javac and java.

If it's an applet, it's more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Having used Java Pathfinder some time back, I know that its not an applet as the other answer worries.

You are getting this error because the Java Pathfinder jar files are not on your classpath. Here is a complete [**Java Pathfinder Getting Started tutorial**](http://www.thejaywalker.net/2005/07/installing-java-path-finder-jpf-on.html) that could help others coming to this old thread.